# keep asking for select default launcher

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-launcher

I'm creating a simple launcher app.
for see my app in available launchers in the phone I add this lines to manifest

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
  </intent-filter>
```

but problem is every time my device turning on device asks for select default luancher even if I select always for default luncher.
my device is a android box "M8S" if thats important.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your Launching activity like this

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: thank's I will try this tomorrow. and accept if that works.now I'm home

Comment: Welcome brother